# Streaming MP3s from Google Drive with download prevented

Tags: google-drive, google-drive-sharing

I need to share a folder of documents, including Word docs, PDFs and MP3s but want to disable the download button. I realise I can't share content and completely prevent people from taking a copy, but I want to remove the download and print buttons which Google Drive allows me to do. I've set that up, and it's working well for the docs and PDFs, but if I set the MP3s to have download blocked they won't play at all. Is there some way of allowing them to stream (which I realise is effectively downloading and playing, but it shouldn't be retained on the client)? Logged in as a viewer (rather than the Drive owner) I've tried right clicking on a blocked MP3 and selecting "Open with > Music Player for Google Drive" but that's not working either.